# How do I set Min Date in Datepicker from another Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I am currently adding validation to my date pickers and am having trouble setting the min date in the **to** date picker to be whatever was chosen in the **from** date picker. I.e if 12-3-15 is selected then the minimum date in the to date picker is 12-3-15. Here is the code I am using:

```
$("#from").datepicker({
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            minDate: new Date(),
            onSelect: function(dateStr) 
            {
            fromDate = new Date(dateStr);
            }
        });

$('#to').datepicker({
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            minDate: ("#from" + "1D"), (<- HERE)
            onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            toDate = new Date(dateStr);

                // Converts date objects to appropriate strings
                fromDate = ConvertDateToShortDateString(fromDate);
                toDate = ConvertDateToShortDateString(toDate);
        });
```

Does anybody know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this working fiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9b512c2/)

Use `option` to set the `minDate` to the second `datepicker`

```
$("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        minDate: new Date(),
        onSelect: function(dateStr) 
        {         
            $("#to").val(dateStr);
            $("#to").datepicker("option",{ minDate: new Date(dateStr)})
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is good but you need to destroy the datepicker of the $to because if not the $to datepicker have still the first date what you select, and remove the option in $to datepicker, this work for me, you not need to make other function for $to.

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateStr) 
    {         
        $("#to").datepicker("destroy");
        $("#to").val(dateStr);
        $("#to").datepicker({ minDate: new Date(dateStr)})
    }
});
```