# set startDate of one datepicker as selected date from another datepicker

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepicker in my page to seletect **From** and **To** dates. **From** datepicker's end date is set to **today** and **To** datepicker's end date is set to **today**. Also i need to set startdate for **To** datepicker to selected date from **From** datepicker. Please help me.

here is my code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="From" id="reportFrom" name="reportFrom" value="<?php echo $reportFrom?>">
<input type="text" placeholder="To" id="reportTo" name="reportTo" value="<?php echo $reportTo;?>">
```

Script:

```
$('#reportFrom').datepicker({
        autoHide: true,
        autoclose: true,
        endDate: new Date(),
        onSelect: function(dateStr) 
        {         
            $("#reportTo").val(dateStr);
            $("#reportTo").datepicker("option",{ startDate: new Date(dateStr)});
        }
    });
    $('#reportTo').datepicker({
        autoHide: true,
        autoclose: true,
        //startDate : $('#reportFrom').val(),
        endDate: new Date()
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at : [How do I set Min Date in Datepicker from another Datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965492/how-do-i-set-min-date-in-datepicker-from-another-datepicker)

Comment: @ravisachaniya i tried the solution in the above mentioned question. but still not working for me

Comment: Is your problem solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="dateFrom" /> 
<input type="text" id="dateTo" />
```

and this is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dateFrom").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#dateFrom').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate());
            $('#dateTo').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to dt1 date
            $('#dateTo').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#dateTo').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var dt1 = $('#dateFrom').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(dt1);
            var dt2 = $('#dateTo').datepicker('getDate');
            if (dt2 == dt1) {
                var minDate = $('#dateTo').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#dateTo').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: no error. r u sure the above example is working. only first datepicker is working

Comment: in your script your second textbox id is not correct. modified and its working . let me try again in page

Comment: Hi @geeth: I have added new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/anand007/f7av3t1o/

Comment: And plz add the jquery libraries as given.

Comment: I did some modifications in your code . check here http://jsfiddle.net/PPSh3/3040/ this is what exactly i need. but this code is not working in my page

Comment: Seems you are not including all jquery files or not in proper order otherwise it will be working. No need to modification i gave you another link but perhaps you are not check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159127/discussion-between-geeth-and-anand-pandey).